# How to pass XML from Cakephp using helper to the iPhone app

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, cakephp

I'm stuck here...

Is there a way we can get results from MySQL database transform to XML with the option of sending as JSON to iPhone App using Cakephp XML helper?

If someone could kindly help me with some answer, that would be much appreciated!

Thank you.
Jae

Comment: So do you want to send it as XML or JSON? cause they are 2 different formats of sending stuffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is expose the functionality of the server to other applications, in this case a mobile phone app. I would suggest that you do it using REST which is detailed here - [Create a REST-style API with CakePHP and XML](http://quinnsupplee.com/blog/quinn/02-11-2010/create-rest-style-api-cakephp-and-xml).

You can change it as need to return JSON as well.